# What is the supremum of $f(z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I know that supremum is the lowest upper bound and infimum is the biggest lower bound. Also according to the supremum axiom, every non-nempty set bounded above has a supremum. Put

$$‎f(z) = \frac{|‎\frac{\sin(z)+\sin(1)-\sin(z+1)}{2-2\cos(1)}|-‎\frac{1}{2}‎\sinh‎(|z|)-‎\cosh‎(|z|)+1 }{‎\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}‎‎‎‎‎\cosh‎‎(\pi|z|)-‎\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}-‎\cosh‎(|z|)+1},\;\;z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}.‎$$

I know that $f(z)$ is bounded above for every $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Now my question is finding the supremum of $f(z)$.To this end I tried to get limit but I could not succeed. I appreciate any help to this matter.

Comment: it is not bounded for $|z| \to 0$.

Comment: Every non empty , bounded set of reals... Are you reffering to complex numbers instead?

Comment: @dmtri, here we deal to $|z|$ which makes the case in real, is it correct?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi, the denominator tends to $0$, but the numerator doesn't

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it does

Comment: @soodehMehboodi,  yes you are right about that ( I missed some vertical lines),  but still you do not know if it is bounded...

Comment: @dmtri, According to my research it should be bounded above.

Comment: This complex $z$ seems misleading,  why not use $x$ positive instead of $abs (z) $? Where does this function come from?

Comment: @ dmtri, I thought, this is clear.